# Find the extrema points for $f(x,y,z)=x-2y+2z$ for $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the extreme points for $f(x,y,z)=x-2y+2z$ for $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ using the polar coordinates $x=\sin\theta \cos\phi, y =\sin\theta\sin\phi,z=\cos\theta$

---

Plugging the spherical coordinates, we obtain
$$f(\sin\theta \cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta) = g(\theta,\phi)=\sin\theta \cos\phi - 2\sin\theta\sin\phi +2\cos\theta$$

We now wish to find the extreme points this function. Computing partial derivatives,
$$g_{1}(\theta,\phi)= \cos\theta\cos\phi-2\cos\theta\sin\phi-2\sin\theta$$
$$g_{2}(\theta,\phi)= -\sin\theta\sin\phi-2\sin\theta\cos\phi$$
Thus,
$$dg(\theta,\phi)=[\cos\theta\cos\phi-2\cos\theta\sin\phi-2\sin\theta \hspace{4mm}-\sin\theta\sin\phi-2\sin\theta\cos\phi]$$
Hence we wish to solve the system of equations
$$\cos\theta\cos\phi-2\cos\theta\sin\phi-2\sin\theta=0, \hspace{4mm}-\sin\theta\sin\phi-2\sin\theta\cos\phi=0$$
How can I solve these equations? I tried using the second equation, from which we have that $\sin\phi = -2\cos\phi$ and substitute that into equation the first one, but to no avail. Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: cant you just use lagrange multipliers

Comment: @CaptainChicky question specifically asked to do it using polar coordinates

Comment: How did you get $\sin\phi=\cos\phi$? It should be either $\sin\theta=0$ or $\sin\phi=-2\cos\phi$.

Comment: @TedShifrin yeah my bad, it was a typo!, I got $\sin{\phi}=-2\cos{\phi}$

Comment: Which tells you $\tan\phi = -2$, so there’s no problem using the first equation to finish. Don’t forget the other cases, too.

Comment: @TedShifrin Exactly, What I ended up doing is I obtained (from the polar coordinates) that $y=-2x$ (equivalent to $\tan{\phi}=-2$), from which I made $f(x,y,z)$ into an equation of $f(x)$ by $y=-2x$, $z=\sqrt{1-5x^2}$. I got function $f(x)=5x+2\sqrt{1-5x^2}$ which can be easily minimised to find $x=\pm \frac{1}{3}$ and the rest sorts itself out and the correct answer is obtained. I was never able to do something with the first polar equation (i.e $g_{1}$), So if you could give a a hint as what to do with it, I would very much appreciate it! (Or perhaps this is the correct approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, your second equation gives us
$$\sin\theta = 0 \quad\text{or}\quad \tan\phi = -2.$$
Now we have to realize that the spherical coordinate system fails when $\sin\theta = 0$ (at the north and south poles there is no well-defined $\phi$), but evaluating $f$ at these points gives $\pm 2$.

Now, when $\tan\phi=-2$, note that your first equation can be rearranged to give
$$2\tan\theta = \cos\phi-2\sin\phi = 5\cos\phi.$$
If $\tan\phi=-2$, then either $\cos\phi=-1/\sqrt5$ and $\sin\phi=2/\sqrt5$ or $\cos\phi=1/\sqrt5$ and $\sin\phi=-2/\sqrt5$. These cases lead respectively to
$$\tan\theta = \mp\sqrt5.$$
You now have enough information to evaluate $f$ at the various critical points.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the spherical coordinates parameterization, the function is

$ f = \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{u} $

where $ \mathbf{c} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ - 2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$

and $ \mathbf{u} = \begin{bmatrix} \sin \theta \cos \phi \\ \sin \theta \sin \phi \\ \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} $

From Schwarz inequality, we know that

$ \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{u} \le \| c \| \| u\| $

with equality if $ \mathbf{c} $ and $\mathbf{u} $ are pointing in the same direction.  Since $\mathbf{u} $ is a unit vector, this means that the maximizing $\mathbf{u} $ is given by

$ \mathbf{u} = \dfrac{\mathbf{c}}{\| c \|} $

Hence,

$\sin \theta \cos \phi = \dfrac{1}{3} $

$ \sin \theta \sin \phi = - \dfrac{2}{3} $

$ \cos \theta = \dfrac{2}{3} $

Which can be readily solved for $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: Spherical coordinates are a hindrance here. It’s far easier directly to find unit vectors parallel to $\mathbf c$.